# Changing a character's forward direction based on camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unity I'm attempting to change a character's forward direction based on where you are looking.  So if you look 45 degrees down and go forward, you will go towards where you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the character's game object actually turning, then all you need to do is set the character's rotation to be the same as the camera's rotation.

If you do mind, you can either do some trigonometry and calculate movement vectors, or you could simply move the camera first, then (in the same frame) move the player to the camera's location.

There's really many ways this could be done, it all depends on what exactly you want.